# Checking if point is in front

Tags: ios, swift, algorithm, 2d, point

I'm building a small application that takes the user's device's lat/long position as well as the heading (true north) and tells you what sort of points of interests are in front of the user. I am getting all my points of interests from google maps api.

I thought the easiest way to do this would be a dot product calculation between my forward vector and the AB vector however I have some false positives.

Here is my code:

```
func isFront(_ p1 : Point, _ p2 : Point, _ p1Heading : Double) -> Bool {

    let forward = Point(cos(p1Heading), sin(p1Heading))

    let AB = Point(p2.x - p1.x, p2.y - p1.y)
    let lenAB = (AB.x * AB.x + AB.y * AB.y).squareRoot()
    let normalAB = Point(AB.x / lenAB, AB.y / lenAB)

    let dot = (normalAB.x * forward.x + normalAB.y * forward.y)

    return (dot > 0)
}
```

So something that is coming back as true but I think shouldnt is:

My location(lat/lng): 42.359291, -71.059638 heading: 173.89306640625

Point of interest (lat/lng): 42.359980, -71.060303

Is this a good approach in figuring out if things are in front or should I look into doing something different?

Answer (score 1):

Yes dot product is a good approach for this but I do not see any dot product in your equations/code I see only messed up gibberish there... If I get it right:


`p1` is device position

`forward` is forward direction

`p2` is tested point

then it should be:

```
let forward = Point(cos(p1Heading), sin(p1Heading))
let dot = ((p2.x-p1.x)*forward.x)+((p2.y-p1.y)*forward.y)
return (dot>0.0)
```

As you can see no lengths are required. Also no normal (even if your normal is not a normal but some gibberish). I think you should read some book/tutorial on vector math basic and check how things are computed here the 2D stuff you mess up:

```
dot(a,b) = a.x*b.x + a.y*b.y
normal(a) = Point(a.y,-a.x)
```